# Hibernate CreateNativeQuery does not close the connection when the exception arises

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, connection, database-connection

I face one issue related to the hibernate `CreateNativeQuery`.

I have executed the query using the `createNativeQuery` and return the `resultList`. If the execution of query fails due to the incorrect query or the reasons, the exception is raised and the connection which is used by the entity manager is not closed. Why the connection is not closed message arrived?

If I use the `createQuery` method I had faced only the exception and connection is closed properly by the entity manager.

What's the reason behind this???

My code is

```
return em.createNativeQuery(queryToExecute).getResultList();
```

Why is the connection not closed if I use the `createNativeQuery` method?

Log Details

```
2015-03-13 11:21:40,504 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection] Closing a statement you left open, please do your own housekeeping: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.registerStatement(WrappedConnection.java:1672) at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.<init>(WrappedStatement.java:105)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.<init>(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:69)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6.<init>(WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6.java:52)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6.wrapPreparedStatement(WrappedConnectionJDK6.java:79)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:404)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1854)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1831)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1826)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:231)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:264)

2015-03-13 11:21:40,506 INFO  [org.jboss.jca.core.api.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManager] IJ000100: Closing a connection for you. Please close them yourself: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@7bc7c07d: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE 
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManagerImpl.registerConnection(CachedConnectionManagerImpl.java:269)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:495)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1854)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1831)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the entire context? Is it closed with other errors? EntityManager can be defined to be closed either programatically, or by the infrastructure (e.g. whenever exiting a service method). Could there be something wrong with the definition? E.g. see here http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/types-of-entitymanagers-application-managed-entitymanager/

Comment: conntecion should be closed by the entitymanager when using the createNativeQuery. but it does not close the connection.

Comment: yes, it is closed with other errors.